# LED Monitor: Native resolution Vs Screen size Vs response time

Tags: display, hardware-rec, user-experience

I'm looking at the available options for a LED monitor having full HD capability (1920x1080 native resolution), and I'm considering the following criteria for choosing a monitor:

- Screen size
- Native resolution
- Refresh time

My question is, what combination of the above would translate to the "best" usability experience, in terms of:

- Least eye strain (the monitor is to be used by my parents, who are 50+ years old)
- Image quality (sharper/better images)
- Video quality (I understand lesser response time translates to lesser artifacts)

If anyone were to add any criteria that I've missed, both in terms of selection of a LED monitor and in terms of viewing experience, feel free to add them in comments/edits...

Answer (score 1):

Least eye strain/Image quality:

You really need to look at more specs then you listed here. E.g. most screens based on TN ([twisted nematic displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD)) are cheap but offer poor viewing angles and inaccurate colours. This is not a problem if you sit in front of your computer.

It is a problem if you get a 30 inch TN screen and set behind the computer with a few people. One setting next to the other and thus looking at the screen via a larger angle.

I can notice the in accurate colours on my 26" IIyama when I open a paint and fill the screen with a single colour. I do not notice it in regular use (e.g. surfing the net).

Video quality/response time:
All of them would do equally well for non gaming.

Response times where an issue in ye old days, when a typical value was 50ms. These days all displays are fast enough for almost any usage. If your parents are into high FPS gaming then get one with a response time then 10ms.

Also, this seems a shopping question. I suggest to rephrase it so it does not get closed.